# How do I use Selenium to Click 'Show More' Button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, lazy-loading, webdriverwait

I am trying to gather a list of doctors from a website.  I am able to get the list from the first page, and the selenium button click seems to work (I can see it advance in the website I am viewing), but I cant extract the elements of the data I want from the "more pages"

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from requests.compat import urljoin
import time

base_url = 'https://doctors.ochsner.org/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')

button  = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mx-auto")

### THIS IS WHAT DOESNT WORK ####

soup.find_all("h3").button.click()
```

I also tried:

```
names = []
for button in button:
    name= soup.find("h3")
    names.append(name)
    button.click()
```

Based on suggestion from @DoctorAgon I also tried the following, but no luck:

```
names = []
for button in button:
    name= [name.text.strip() for name in soup.find_all('h3')]
    names.append(name)
    button.click()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')
    time.sleep(30)
```

I would like the output to be a list of names from the entire list (looks like there should be over 2900.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey there, what is the error message your are seeing? Or if there is no error, what does `print(soup.find_all('h3'))` print out?

Comment: There is no error.  Soup.find_all(‘h3’) prints a list of the doctors on the first webpage

Comment: Ahhh Ok. Try calling `BeautifulSoup(...)` again after you click "more pages"

Comment: I tried and it doesnt seem to change the output.  I edited my original question with changes i made based on your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the list of doctors from the website `https://doctors.ochsner.org/` clicking on the button with text as **SHOW MORE RESULTS**, you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException 

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://doctors.ochsner.org/")
  myLength = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='flip-card-header']//h3"))))
  while True:
      try:
          driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 400)")
          WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mx-auto"))).click()
          WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='flip-card-header']//h3")) > myLength)
          titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='flip-card-header']//h3")
          myLength = len(titles)
      except TimeoutException:
          break
  for title in titles:
      print(title.text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Tarek Abdallah, MD
  Irfan Ahsan, DPM
  Lindsey Manson Aldridge, CCC-A
  Peggy Jo Alker, NP
  Lisa Casteigne Alleman, PA-C
  Katherine Alleyne, PA-C
  Ronald Gerard Amedee, MD
  Brian Anthony, MD
  Jennifer Archie, MD
  Jeffrey C. Arnold, NP
  Muhammad K. Arshad, MD
  Jimi Aucoin, CNMW
  Amer Awad, MD
  Colin Bailey, MD
  William Heritage Baird, MD
  Dale Banks Jr, NP
  Aditya Bansal, MD
  James Barrow, MD
  Michael Bates, MD
  Katherine L. Baumgarten, MD
  Joanna Bayles, DO
  Francine Belleville, MD
  Joseph Benevento, MD
  William Bennett, MD
  Michael Bernard, MD
  Mattie Berry, CNM
  Neil Billeaud, MD
  Christopher M. Blais, MD
  Leslie Anne Blake, MD
  Lionel E. Boudreaux, OD
  Laura Classen Boykin, MD
  Chad Cody Kaolaniman Braden, MD
  James W. Bragg Jr, MD
  Misty Breakfield, PA
  Patrick C. Breaux, MD
  Mindy Brewer, NP
  Jeanenne Brignac, MD
  Daniel R. Bronfin, MD
  Burke J. Brooks Jr., MD
  Kefla G. Brown, OD
  Elisecia Brown, NP
  Russell Brown, MD
  Benjamin Bryan Browning, MD
  Kevin-Steven Buford, MD
  Aden A. Burka, PhD
  Todd Burstain, MD
  Jennifer Burtch, NP
  Angelle Bush, NP
  Jaime Esteban Bustamante, MD
  Danielle M. Calix, MD
  Ilias Caralopoulos, MD
  John Carter, MD
  William J. Carter, MD
  Michael E. Cash, MD
  Ravi Chauhan
  Mohammad Cheema, MD
  Daniel Chehebar, DO
  W. Stephen Choate, MD
  Kimberly Choina-Karamat, ACNP-BC
  Marvin W. Clifford, LCSW
  John T. Cole, MD
  Jared F. Collins, MD
  Cristen Crain, NP
  Curtis J. Creed, MD
  Jonathan Crowder, MD
  Marvin Dair, MD
  Khaled A. Dajani, MD
  Joseph Dalovisio, MD
  Long Dang, MD
  Anjali Dasgupta, MD
  Casey Daste Reed, MD
  William E. Davis, MD
  Robin Davis, MD
  Carter T Davis, MD
  Donalyn DeBlanc, FNP-C
  Charles DeGravelles, MD
  Thomas Delahoussaye, MD
  Bethanie Delaney, CNM
  Jared Dendy, MD
  Daniel Denis, MD
  Alicia DePaula, MD
  Sapna V. Desai, MD
  Laurephile Desrosiers, DO
  Daniel A. DeVun Jr, MD
  Charles J. DiCorte, MD
  Homeyar K. Dinshaw, MD
  David J. Donaldson Jr, MD
  Wendy J.G. Doneyhue, MD
  Adam M. Dowling, MD
  Lingling Du, MD
  Scott Dufrene, LCSW
  Michael A. Dunn, MD
  Andre Duplantis, MD
  Timothy Durel, MD
  Sherrie Eakin, FNP
  Lynn S. Eckhardt, MSN
  Mark Effron, MD
  Eric Ehrensing, MD
  Ibrahim K. El-Abbassi, MD
  Mini J. Elnaggar, MD
  Noah A. Emerson, DO
  W. Brooks Emory, MD
  Nona Kathryn Epstein, MD
  Callie Estes, NP
  Jacob Estes, MD
  Bryan M. Evans, MD
  Ruben D. Fabrega, MD
  Thomas Roy Fairley, OD
  Antoine Joseph Faucheaux III, MD
  Charles H. Faucheux, MD
  Olga Fermo, MD
  Sara Ehrensing Fernandez, MD
  Laura Finn, MD
  James B. Fitzpatrick, MD
  Janet Floyd, CNM
  Joshua Fowler, MD
  Sarah Freiberg, PA
  Andrew Fuller, MD
  Rajiv Gala, MD
  Julia B. Garcia-Diaz, MD
  Christopher Garnett, MD
  L'Issa L. Gates, MD
  Matthew Gaudet, MD
  Michelle Genet, MD
  Harley G. Ginsberg, MD
  Amy Glick, MD
  Peter Goertz, MD
  Leah Gonski, MD
  Jessica Gorham, MD
  Natasha Goss-Voisin, MD
  Andrew W. Gottschalk, MD
  Nicholas Goyeneche, MD
  Sonia Granera, MD
  Nakash Grant, MD
  Dwight A. Green, MD
  Christopher P. Grenier, MD
  Asahel Gridley, MD
  Dana Gruber, PhD
  Joseph Guarisco, MD
  Maged Guirguis, MD
  Lisa Guzman, NP
  Laura Haar, PA-C
  Lawrence L. Haber, MD
  Bennett Hailey, MD
  Kelli D Hall, MD
  Megan Hartman, MD
  Seth Hayes, MD
  Jack W. Heidenreich, MD
  David Heinen, MD
  Justin Hendricks, MD
  Jeanne Herman, OD
  Lindsey Hill, CNM
  Kasey Hill, MD
  Michael Hines, MD
  Jennifer V. Hogan, MD
  Ted J. Hudspeth, MD
  Robin Ivester, MD
  Daniel Jacob, MD
  Kyle Jakob, MD
  Sophy A. Jancich, MD
  Louis O. Jeansonne IV, MD
  Nicole Alma Delores Jones, MD
  Nadja Jones, MD
  Amy Jones, MD
  Kelly Jones, AuD
  Brandi K. Jones, MD
  Melissa Jordan, MD
  Marlon Joseph, MD
  Jamie Juckett, PA-C
  James Kalyvas, MD
  Charles M. Kantrow III, MD
  Joseph Keen, DO
  Sandra A. Kemmerly, MD
  Chandana Keshavamurthy, MD
  Naseer A. Khan, MD
  Emily Kinsley, NP
  David S. Kirsch, MD
  Teresa Klainer, MD
  Meghan Klavans, MD
  Richard C. Kline, MD
  Colleen Knoop, NP
  Alicia Castleberry Kober, MD
  Anna Kosztowski, MD
  Cheryl Krewsky, DNP
  John Kwon, MD
  Alisha Lacour, MD
  Diego Lara, MD
  Gregory Larsen, MD
  Michele Larzelere, PhD
  Carl (Chip) J. Lavie Jr, MD
  Gloria M. Leary, MD
  Leslie LeBlanc, NP
  Guy Lefort, MD
  Elizabeth B. LeJeune, ANP-C
  Megan Lemon, NP
  William Lennarz, MD
  Allison Leonard, MD
  Dean Leone, MD
  Lauren Leslie, DO
  Clint Lincoln, MD
  Kilee Lincoln, MD
  Michael Lindley, MD
  Felicia Lindsey, PA
  Amy P. Linn, CNM
  J. David Linson, OD
  Katherine M. Loftfield, MD
  Emma M. Long, PA-C
  Chantal B. Lorio, DPM
  George E. Loss Jr, MD
  Craig Lotterman, MD
  Liudmila Lysenko, MD
  Scott L. Macicek, MD
  Aimee Mackey, MD
  Jayesh Madrecha, DO
  Dee Malkerneker, MD
  Pavan Malur, MD
  Stacy A. Mandras, MD
  Michael J. Marcello, MD
  Jeffrey P. Marino, MD
  Ory Marrioneaux, PA-C
  Benjamin Marshall, MD
  Jeanine Martin, DO
  Vicki Matherne, CNM
  Jonette H. Mayer, MD
  D. Anthony Mazzulla, MD
  Michelle McCloskey, NP
  Mary L. McCormick, MD
  Jamie McDonald, CNM
  LesLeigh McGee, DPM
  Harold McGrade, MD
  Shannon McGuire, MD
  Kyle McMullen, MD
  Nneka Meka, DPM
  Uma Menon, MD
  Joseph A. Miceli III, MD
  James M. Milburn, MD
  Belinda Miller, NP
  Ward Miller, NP
  Michelle Mims, MD
  Tara E. Mitchell, MD
  Brian Mizuki, PsyD
  Oliver Mollere, MD
  Lawrence Montelibano, MD
  Willard Moore III, MD
  Stephen Moran, MD
  Michael G. Morgan, MD
  Daniel P. Morin, MD
  Gregory Morris, MD
  George B. Morris IV, MD
  Granville Morse III, MD
  William Moss, MD
  Xavier Mousset, MD
  Rebekah Ann Murray, PA
  Pamela Musacchia, MD
  Lauren Mutter, MD
  Zola M. N'Dandu, MD
  Jennifer Nakamura, MD
  Matias Nauts, MD
  Joshua Neeson, DPM
  Brian K. Nelson, OD
  Giang Jane Nguyen, DPM
  Tu-Anh Nguyen, PA-C
  Jenee Nguyen, NP
  Le Nguyen, MD
  Laura Winkeler Nicosia, MD
  Ajsa Ana Sofija Nikolic, MD
  Dmitriy M. Niyazov, MD
  Jonathan D. Nussdorf, MD
  Juan Ochoa Gautier, MD
  J Lockwood Ochsner Jr, MD
  Moira L. Ogden, MD
  Maricelle Ong, MD
  Myriam Ortiz De Jesus, MD
  Erin Owens, FNP
  Kiran Kumar Padigala, MD
  Jason Park, MD
  John Passman, PA-C
  Pinky Patel, MD
  Hamang M. Patel, MD
  Rajan Patel, MD
  Emily Paulk, MD
  Benjamin Peeler, MD
  Yvette S. Peevy, MA
  Linnea Perkins, MD
  Gloria Peters, NP
  Diana M. Peterson, MD
  Brian L. Pettiford
  Erin Pierce, NP
  Michael Pinsky, MD
  Kristin Pippin, PA
  Osei Prempeh, MD
  Melissa Pretus-Hudson, NP
  Salima Qamruddin, MD
  Amy Gaudet Rabalais, MD
  Emily J. Ramee, MD
  L. Prasad Ravipati, MD
  Arnab Ray, MD
  Ashley Reda, PA-C
  Tara Redwantz, APRN
  Ronald R. Reichel, MD
  Renee F. Reymond, MD
  Kellin Reynolds, MD
  Matthew Rice, MD
  Gary M. Rich, MD
  Audrey Richard, PA-C
  Treena Richard, NP
  Matthew Rivenburgh, MD
  Amy Rivere, MD
  Brett Roberts, MD
  Jake Rodi, MD
  Cornel Rogers, MD
  Ricardo V. Romero, MD
  M. Stephanie Roseboom, NP
  Sheryl Lynn Rowland, MD
  J. Kyle Russo, MD
  Priya Sahu, MD
  Christopher Sanchez, MD
  Mahmoud Sarmini, MD
  Robert John Sawyer II, PhD
  Christopher Schneider, PA
  Brian Schulte, MD
  Troy G. Scroggins Jr, MD
  Leonardo Seoane, MD
  Mary Lou W. Seymour, MD
  Phyllis Shnaider, LCSW
  Robin Shoun, NP
  Peter Simoneaux, MD
  M. Kellie Smith, MD
  James W. Smith, MD
  Amy Smith, AuD
  Brett Sorensen, DPM
  Jeremy Thomas Spencer, MD
  Stephen Spindel, MD
  Amy Springer, MD
  Stacey Standridge, APRN
  Daryl Stanga, PA-C
  Russell W. Steele, MD
  Rodney Steiner, MD
  Andrew Steven, MD
  Merrill Stewart, MD
  Bruce Stewart, MD
  James Stoll, MD
  Colleen Story, NP
  Anna Strahan, FNP-C
  Natalie Stubbs, NP
  Alexander Sung, MD
  Douglas Swift, MD
  Shelly Swindler, MD
  Murad Talahma, MD
  Christine Talley, NP
  Robert Tassin, MD
  Sarena Teng, MD
  Scott Thames, MD
  George Therapondos, MD
  Saravanan Thiagarajan, MD
  John Thien, MD
  Daniel Thomas, MD
  Shontell N. Thomas, MD
  Alisha Thomas, NP
  Vijay Bhasker Reddy Thumma, MD
  Michael C. Townsend, MD
  Casey Tusa, AuD
  Sydney Tyson, CNM
  Gia Tyson, MD
  Gabriel Uwaifo, MD
  Sreekanth Vasireddy, MD
  Robert J. Vasquez Jr, MD
  Salvador Velazquez, MD
  Hector O. Ventura, MD
  Richard Vinroot Jr, MD
  Genny Vo, OD
  Natalie Voithofer, MD
  Michael Voorhies, MD
  Gregory R. Vorhoff, MD
  Julie Wang, MD
  Rajasekharan Warrier, MD
  Yolonda Webb, MD
  Stacia Williams, NP
  Vera Williams, NP
  Daneeka A. Woods, APRN
  Lindsey Xiao, DPM
  Brian J. Young, MD
  Thomas W. Young, MD
  Zhe Zheng, MD
  Freddy Michel Abi-Samra, MD
  Vincent R. Adolph, MD
  Shameem Akhtar, MD
  Aderonke F. Akingbola, MD
  Tlaloc Alferez, MD
  Ali Amkieh, MD
  Derek Anderson, MD
  Leandro C. Area, MD
  Laurence W. Arend, MD
  Ahmet Bedestani, MD
  Tracy Benzing, MD
  Jeffrey Benzing, MD
  Karen B. Blessey, MD
  Robert M. Bober, MD
  Dayna Bolton, DPM
  Robin Bone, MD
  Jennifer Braaten, MD
  Jeryl Breaux, MD
  Jennifer Brunet, MD
  Elizabeth Buras, NP
  Tanya S. Busenlener, MD
  Monica A. Butz, APRN
  Natalie H. Bzowej, MD
  Michael Castine, MD
  Pedro Cazabon, MD
  Walter Ross Cazayoux, MD
  Gassan Chaiban, MD
  Robert Chasuk, MD
  Teresa Christian, PsyD
  Ari J. Cohen, MD
  Sean M. Collins, MD
  Anne Colwart, NP
  Allison Conravey, MD
  Kodi Fay Crisp-Coleman, MD
  Terence C D'Souza, MD
  Mahmoud Daftary, MD
  S. Colby Danna, MD
  Tiffany Davis, MD
  Tara T. Deeney, MD
  Nicholas DiSalvo, MD
  Bryan Dudoussat, MD
  Craig A. Ehrensing, MD
  Clement Eiswirth Jr, MD
  William Ellerbe, MD
  John Edward Erffmeyer, MD
  Vineeta Estes, MD
  Samuel J. Ferris, MD
  Susan K Fielkow, MD
  Conar Fitton, MD
  Matthew Fletcher, MD
  Amanda Fontenot, MD
  Thomas Ford, MD
  Jo Foret, MSN
  Kate Freeman, MD
  Michael Friel, MD
  Kenneth A. Gaddis, MD
  Eugenia P. Gary, MD
  Patricia Gendusa, MD
  Steven J. Granier, MD
  Frank Guidry, MD
  Nichole Guillory, MD
  Timothy Haman, MD
  David B. Hebert, MD
  Brian Helmstetter, DO
  Jason B. Hill, MD
  Keith A. Holmes, MD
  David J. Houghton, MD
  Jamie B. Huddleston, MD
  Jamie Hutchinson, MD
  Trang P. Huynh, MD
  Richard K. Imsais, MD
  James Jancuska, MD
  Haytham Kawji, MD
  Robert M. Kelly, OD
  Kathryn G. Kerisit, MD
  Bahij Nadim Khuri, MD
  Terry D. King, MD
  Sebastian Koga, MD
  Ellen R. Kruger, MD
  Blakely Kute, MD
  Eric L. Laborde, MD
  Brian Ladner, MD
  Angele LaFleur, DO
  Donavon Neil Lafleur, OD
  James Lam, MD
  Zoe L. Larned, MD
  Michele L. Larroque, MD
  Richard T. LeBlanc Jr, MD
  Ryan Lee, MD
  Lydia Lewis, MD
  Azikiwe Lombard, MD
  Sherri A. Longo, MD
  Alberto M. Lopez, MD
  Richard G. Marek Jr, MD
  Matthew Douglas Mcelveen, MD
  Robert Dale McKinney II, MD
  Douglas K. Mendoza, MD
  Kendra LaShawn Michael, MD
  Melissa M. Montgomery, MD
  Asghar Naqvi, MD
  Khoa Nguyen, MD
  Ian Nguyen, MD
  Elise Nicaud, MD
  Lisa H Nicoletti, APRN
  Ha Kim Ninh, OD
  Adwoa S. Opoku-Boateng, MD
  John Oubre, MD
  Brandon Page, MD
  Archana Paine, MD
  Elizabeth Peacock, MD
  Wendy Peterson, NP
  Glenda B. Petroff, FNP
  Dianna Phan, MD
  Kevin C. Plaisance, MD
  Nichole M. Polin, MD
  Glenn M. Polin, MD
  Lester J. Prats Jr, MD
  Sydney C. Prescott, MSN
  Robert J. Quinet, MD
  Arif Qureshi, MD
  Sidney Beau Raymond, MD
  Lisa Renee Rushing, FNP-BC
  Aldo J. Russo, MD
  Todd Sanderson, MD
  Korak Sarkar, MD
  Suma Satti, MD
  Maxime G.J. Savard, DPM
  Brooke Cranfield Schexnaildre, MD
  Claire Schwegel, FNP-BC
  Michelle L Seoane, ANP-C
  Pulin A. Shah, MD
  Shamita Shah, MD
  Mehul Sheth, MD
  Timothy Short, DPM
  Stacy D. Siegendorf, MD
  Edward David Sledge Jr, MD
  Roger D. Smith, MD
  Malik Spady, MD
  Gerald Joseph Sparks, MD
  Dasarathy Srinivas, MD
  Andrew St. Martin, MD
  W. C. Charles Sternbergh III, MD
  Srikanth Tamma, MD
  Lauren Thomassie, MD
  Juan Carlos Torres, MD
  Ryan Truxillo, MD
  Raul Varela, MD
  Priya P. Velu, MD
  Vu Vuong, MD
  Katrina Wade, MD
  Sean Waldron, MD
  Suneeta S. Walia, MD
  Sacha Wax, MD
  Tamika Webb-Detiege, MD
  Brandon Weeks, DO
  Cheree Wheeler-Duke, MD
  Christopher J. White, MD
  Michael A. Wiedemann, MD
  John Wood, MD
  James B. Wooldridge Jr., MD
  Mary Yu, MD
  Elizabeth Zabel, MD
  Jamie Zampell, MD
  Joshua D. Parks, MD
  John P. McCrossen, MD
  Hans Adams, MD
  Andrew Adams, MD
  Stephen Adjei, MD
  Ariel Aguillard, MD
  Milton W. Anderson, MD
  Bridget A. Bagert, MD
  Alexandra Band, DO
  Stephen F. Bardot, MD
  Hernan A. Bazan, MD
  Gurpal S. Benning, MD
  Tara G. Berner, MD
  Erin E. Biro, MD
  John S. Bolton, MD
  Joseph L. Breault, MD
  P William Brown, MD
  Jeffrey Burnham, MD
  Kenneth J. Byrd Jr, MD
  W. Aaron Caraway, MD
  Daniela Cardozo, MD
  Jacqueline Carter, MD
  Marshall Lynn Cauley, OD
  Paul Celestre, MD
  George F. Chimento, MD
  Michael B. Cohen, MD
  Jeffrey Allen Colegrove, OD
  Tyrone J. Collins, MD
  Craig Conard, MD
  Sean E. Connolly, MD
  James D. Conway, MD
  Janet W. Cook, MD
  Alicia Cool, MD
  Nicola S. Corbett, MD
  Ralph L. Corsetti, MD
  Brian Cruz, MD
  Jose M. Cusco, MD
  Dennis M. Dale, MD
  Julie G. Danna, MD
  Erin Frances Dauterive, MD
  Michael Davis, MD
  W Edward Davis III, MD
  Erin W Derbigny, MD
  Trent Desselle, MD
  Kevin Doulens, MD
  Sanjay G. Dravid, MD
  Troy U. Drewitz, MD
  Evan L. Dvorin, MD
  Lauren S. Elder, MD
  DeAnna Elsea, MD
  Helene Erickson, MD
  Kenneth Ewane, MD
  Adelaide Francois, MD
  Elizabeth Shane French, MD
  Ronald J. French Jr, MD
  George M. Fuhrman, MD
  Brian Galofaro, MD
  H. Devon Graham III, MD
  Patricia M. Granier, MD
  Ewelina B. Griffin, MD
  Leonard Grubstein, LCSW
  J Lindhe Guarisco, MD
  Jeffrey A. Guillmette, MD
  Amy Hammons, MD
  Angela Carolyn Harris, DO
  Christian P. Hasney, MD
  Dean A. Hickman, MD
  Terrell C. Hicks, MD
  Howard Hirsch, MD
  Sarah W. Holt, DO
  Ijeoma N. Innocent-Itauh, MD
  Nina M. Jackson-Battiste, NP
  Atif Jadoon, MD
  Surma D. Jain, MD
  Kristin M. Johnson, DO
  Natalia M. Jolliff, DO
  Brian Kann, MD
  Abdul Baset Khan, MD
  Sammy Khatib, MD
  Arthur Kim, MD
  Ronald Kluchin, MD
  Leise Rose Knoepp, MD
  Georgia S. Lea, MD
  Eric Letonoff, DO
  Ricki Linarello, ANP-C
  Stephen M. Lindsey, MD
  Melissa Bagwell Love, MD
  Shannon Lovell, LCSW
  David A. Margolin, MD
  Sarah Mason, NP
  Jim Mautner, MD
  Jolie May
  Laura F McCormick, MD
  Edward McCoul, MD
  Susan N. McNamara, MD
  Lesley Meng, MD
  Sharnette Miles, DPM
  Tammy Mitchell, MD
  Scott C. Montgomery, MD
  Brian Moore, MD
  George Morris III, MD
  Kristin Wemple Morvant, MD
  Alexander Kenneth Mulamula, MD
  Karen A. Muratore, MD
  Obinna Nnedu, MD
  Sherise Rose Olivier-Wittmann, MD
  Mia Oubre, NP
  P. Eugene Parrino, MD
  Reinaldo Rampolla, MD
  Margaret A. Roberie, MD
  Sean M. Roberts, MD
  Kimsey H. Rodriguez, MD
  Alison Rodriguez, MD
  Esteban O. Romano, MD
  Cesar Roque, MD
  William T. Sargent, MD
  Richelle D. Schiro, MD
  Jason Schrock, MD
  Matthew Schuette, MD
  Philip Skelding, MD
  Erika Smith, MD
  Fayne Marie St. John, MD
  Thomas Strong, MD
  Olawale Sulaiman, MD
  Kathleen Sullivan, MD
  Muhammad Ali Syed, MD
  Marcie Colleen Tauzin Wilkinson, MD
  Sonya Trinh, MD
  Heather Urrego, MD
  Joshua Vallelungo, MD
  Juan Vargas, MD
  David Vargas, MD
  Amy Vaughan, MD
  Karan Verma, MD
  Janos Voros, MD
  Marcus L. Ware, MD
  Michael F. Wasserman, MD
  Mia Weber, MD
  Anna White, MD
  Patience Wildenfels, MD
  Rachel D. Wissner, MD
  Theodore Atkinson, MD
  James Dudley Atkinson IV, MD
  Christopher R. Babycos, MD
  Pierre Blemur, MD
  Peter B. Blessey, MD
  Shrisha Bodana, DO
  Victoria Z. Brandt, NP
  Cuong J. Bui, MD
  Glenn Butt, MD
  Osvaldo Camilo, MD
  Daniel Canter, MD
  Kathy Jo Carstarphen, MD
  Tracie N. Carter, MD
  Jennifer Chamberlain, MD
  Nicole M. Charbonnet, MD
  Pavan Chava, DO
  Andrea Cothern, NP
  Rachel Csaki, MD
  Luke Cvitanovic, MD
  Rory Jude Duffour, MD
  Timothy Duke, MD
  Guergana Enikova, MD
  H. Sprague Eustis Jr, MD
  Ilana Fortgang, MD
  Stephen Fortunato, MD
  Catherine Benoit Gahn, FNP-BC
  Joan Gatte, FNP
  Lois H. Gesn, MD
  Veronica Gillispie, MD
  Nigel Girgrah, MD
  Glenn M. Gomes, MD
  Monique Pierce Hamilton, MD
  Whitney Hardy, MD
  Robert I. Hart, MD
  Cathryn C. Hassett, MD
  Sharon Yoder Hedges, MD
  Kristin Sullivan Johnson, MD
  Deryk G. Jones, MD
  Shobha Joshi, MD
  Lutifat A. Kashimawo, MD
  Fawad A. Khan, MD
  Stanley Kordisch, MD
  Monika Lammi, MD
  Lora M. Langefels, MD
  Elizabeth R. Lapeyre, MD
  Anna Lara, MD
  Emily R. Lawrentz, PA-C
  Matthew H. LeBoeuf, MD
  Ruthie Long, NP
  Stacy M. Luna, PA-C
  Daniel McGovern, DPM
  Matthew A. McQueen, MD
  Molly E. McRae, FNP-BC
  Julie Mermilliod, MD
  Aimee Mistretta Hasney, MD
  Timothy B. Molony, MD
  Kristen Amanda Morris, LCSW
  Brian G. Morris, MD
  Mohammad Q. Nawaz, MD
  James H. Newcomb Jr, MD
  Colleen Ann Newman, MSN
  Brandy A. Panunti, MD
  Jennifer Moorhead Parkerson, MD
  Stephen R. Ramee, MD
  Marilyn C. Ray, MD
  Shilpa Mainampati Reddy, MD
  Wanda Robinson, MD
  Farjaad Siddiq, MD
  Victoria A. Smith, MD
  Misty Suri, MD
  Robert W. Taylor, MD
  Chris Theodossiou, MD
  Austin C. Thomas, MD
  Joanna M. Togami, MD
  Angelique Torres, APRN
  Robert J. Treuting, MD
  Amy Elizabeth Truitt, MD
  Alvah Tyson Wickboldt, MD
  Maria Wilson, MD
  Ryan Winters, MD
  Howard H. Woo, MD
  Christopher J. Wormuth, MD
  Amanda Wright, MD
  Diane Katz Africk, MD
  Aimee Allen, NP
  Ann Margaret Azcuy, MD
  Ambuga Badari, MD
  Raymond Baez, MD
  Nicole Bailey, APRN
  Brian Brogle, MD
  Mirjana Bukara, MD
  John Burvant, MD
  Mary Byars, CNM
  Ana Khouri Catinis, MD
  Ella Unkyong Choe, MD
  Riza Elaine Cruz, MD
  Troy Davis, MD
  Christie V. DeGrange, MD
  Susana L. Dipp, MD
  Hazem Essam Eissa, MD
  Ann Faucheux, PA
  Andrea Garaudy, MD
  Christopher Gray, MD
  Nathan Harrison, MD
  Terence L. Hauver II, MD
  Mary Virginia Howell, NP
  Shelley Huff, OD
  Brian P. Jones, MD
  Amin Kamyar, MD
  Christine M. Keating, MD
  Andrew Lawton, MD
  Kenneth Long, DO
  John Marker, MD
  Beverly McCoy, NP
  Hillary Montalbano, NP
  Judy M. Moreau, DO
  Melanie R. Oldendorf, PA-C
  Angela Marie Parise, MD
  Dawn Pekarek, MD
  Kimberly Prather, NP
  Eugene Ramsay, MD
  William S. Richardson, MD
  Renee Ross, PA
  Avery H. Sampson, MD
  Shannon Seals, MD
  J. Brian Seymour, MD
  Leslie E. Sisco-Wise, MD
  Gay Story, MD
  Karen America Toribio, MD
  Fernando Andres Urrego, MD
  Colin Van Hook, MD
  Herbert W. Van Horn III, MD
  Erin Vaughn, MD
  John Vu, MD
  Elizabeth Vulevich, NP
  Lesley Walsh, MD
  Monica Williams, MD
  Samuel S. Andrews II, MD
  Catherine Badeaux, CNM
  Bryan Bertucci, MD
  Robert "Allen" Butler, MD
  Kiran Chava, MD
  Bradley Collins, MD
  Claudia Cuervo, MD
  Ralph F. Dauterive Jr., MD
  Larry Ferdinand Jr, MD
  David Galarneau, MD
  Yvonne E. Gilliland, MD
  George Golightly, MD
  Christopher P. Guarisco, MD
  Sherida Jackson, FNP-BC
  Quyen Kraemer, NP
  Aimee Staser Kramer, MD
  Megan Mackey, CNM
  Kuntal Mohare, MD
  Robert Ramirez, DO
  Lisa F. Richards, MD
  Brenda Salmeron, APRN
  Eve Scopelitis, MD
  Jennifer Velander, MD
  S. Shari Vicente, NP
  Michael A. Wilensky, MD
  Yihong Zheng, MD
  Matthew Bergstedt, MD
  Jessica Harvey, PA
  Susan Hendricks, MD
  Lynette Heslet, PhD
  Dywanda Lewis, MD
  Keith Luper, DPM
  Aimee T. McHugh, PT
  Chung Pham, MD
  John K. Willis II, MD
  Jerald M. Zakem, MD
  Brigid McCue, MD
  John T. Patterson, MD
  Helen Stavros, LCSW
  Abdolazim Akhondzadeh, MD
  Ryan Arnold, MD
  Megan Binder, PhD
  Michael Christopher Boucree, MD
  Mary Braud, PMHNP
  Vinod Chainani, MD
  David T. Coffin, MD
  Nancy Elizabeth Diethelm, MD
  Lisa Diethelm, MD
  Erica A. Diggs, MD
  Julie Doan, MD
  Lauren Dunn, MD
  Jennifer Durst, MD
  Parrish T. Eilers, MD
  Jerry Evans, MD
  Coleatha Fowler, NP
  Victor Manuel M. Garcia-Prats, MD
  Brandy Glorioso, PA
  David Greenhouse, MD
  Bonnie Hanson, PA-C
  Abdul Mukhtadir Khan, MD
  Michael Knisley, MD
  Vikas Kothapalli, MD
  Thomas Laborde, MD
  Anne Marsala, MD
  Marianne Maumus, MD
  Renee Melancon, PA-C
  Scott Michaelson, DO
  Jose Najul-Seda, MD
  Patricia C. Porada, MD
  Melanie Powell, MD
  Hilari Shae Sauncy, MD
  Janak Shah, MD
  Gregory Shamitko, MD
  Amy Sheeder, MD
  Dennis Sonnier, MD
  Susan Diane Taylor, MD
  T. Michael Truxillo, MD
  Scott M. Zainey, MD
  Jessica Roybal, MD
  Wendell W. Tang, MD
  Mollie M. Alarcon, Ed D
  Doris W. Lin, MD
  Andrea J. Linscott, PhD
  Randi McMillan, LDN
  Lisa Newell Schuler, MHA
  Johanna Schutte, LCSW
  Angela Tillman, LCSW
  Dustin Abadco, MD
  Samy Abdelghani, MD
  Anshul Acharya, MD
  Quianne Aguillard, NP
  Chima Akunne, DPM
  Peggy Alexander, APRN
  Hiba Ali, MD
  Layla Alizadeh, MD
  Brent Allen, MD
  Nicole Allen, MSN
  Bronwyn Allen, NP
  David Quentin Alleva, MD
  Cielo Alleyn, MD
  Casey Almonte, MD
  Caroline Alquist, MD
  Bonnie Alvey, APRN
  Shilpa Amara, MD
  Nimesh Amin, DO
  Brian G Ammon, PA-C
  Kweli Amusa, MD
  Kiran Anand, MD
  Michael Anders, LCSW
  Carmen Anderson, MD
  Kelly Anderson, NP
  Corey P Andras, AGACNP-BC
  Tanya Andrepont, MCD
  Christo Arbonies, MD
  Ashley Areaux, PA-C
  Adrienne D Arnold, CPNP-AC
  Beth Arredondo, PhD
  Teshawn Ash, NP
  Frederick H. Asher, MD
  Amy Aucoin, NP
  Mark Awolesi, MD
  Benjamin Azan, MD
  Miriam Azuoru, MD
  Jonathan Babin, MD
  Mirza K. Baig, MD
  Charitraheen Ann Baijnath, MD
  Taylor Bailey, NP
  Jeffery A. Baker, MD
  Karee Balfantz, LDN
  Lauren Ballard, FNP
  Arden Ballard, PA-C
  Irielle L. Banks, APRN
  Mona Bansal, MD
  Brandie Baque, CRNP
  Anna Barham, PA-C
  Marte Baro, MD
  Lauren Barousse, PA-C
  Aimee Barrois, NNP
  Jennifer Barrow, MD
  Heather Bartley, AuD
  Laura Elizabeth Bateman, MD
  Alicia Augustine Bates, CDE
  Jerry Batson, NP
  Jessica Baudier, FNP
  Lydia Angela Louise Bazzano, MD
  Timothy Beaty, MD
  Edwin Norquist Beckman, MD
  Michelle Becnel, MD
  Miriam Becnel, PA-C
  Updesh Bedi, MD
  Kenneth Allen Bell, MD
  Michael Benoit, PA
  Catherine Benoit, PA-C
  Lauren Bergeron, MD
  Lisa Bernhard, MD
  Kayleigh Binet, PA-C
  Natalie Dawn Bingham, MD
  Laurie A. Bishop, MD
  Oren W. Blalock, MD
  Lynsi Blanchard, PA-C
  Laura Blanchard, NP
  Michael Blanchard, MD
  Kim Bland, MD
  Lawrence Blonde, MD
  Catherine Blouin, CRNA
  Gabriella Marie Bluett-Mills, MD
  Edward Ira Bluth, MD
  Cheree' Bodden, NP
  Bridgitte Boehm, NNP
  Anneliese Boettcher, PhD
  Julie Bogdan, PA-C
  Humberto E. Bohorquez, MD
  Jonathan Bonilla, MD
  Ann Borreson, MD
  Jonah Borskey, CRNA
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and was able to get the doctors list

the issue here is, page contains only 20 initially. when u click more, next 20 is fetched.  so, you need to click on "Show more" till your total is reached and after the click wait for the elements to load.

For example, initially u have 20. when u click on load more, you get another 20. So, wait for total to become 40.

In java

```
List<WebElement> el = null;

        for (int i = 19; i < 2918; i = i + 20) {
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(By.className("flip-card-header"), i));

            el = driver.findElements(By.className("flip-card-header"));
            System.out.println("Size now is " + el.size());
            driver.findElement(By.className("ais-InfiniteHits-loadMore")).click();
        }

        el.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getText()));
        driver.quit();
```

Comment: thanks.  I kind of follow the logic (I don't know java).  But isnt time.sleep() in my example accomplishing the same thing as WebDriverWait?